# How to pause a simple canvas game with a HTML button?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have created a simple pong game after following some simple tutorials on YouTube.

The problem is that the game does not have a pause function (e.g. when pressing the `Pause` button, the game should pause/resume). I need help with the HTML button, which has a pause value, but does not work. I would like the canvas to stop on the click of the `Pause` button and to resume when it is clicked again.

**The tutorial says to add something to publish it, but I don't know what to do.**

### Code

**HTML**

```
<canvas style="cursor: pointer;" id="pong" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<div class="animation">
    <button class="btn" onclick="RefreshWindow()">Restart</button>
</div>
<div class="animation">
    <button class="btn" onclick="...my problem is here">Pause</button>
</div>

<script src="js/pong.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// select canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById("pong");

// getContext of canvas = methods and properties to draw and do a lot of thing to the canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// load sounds
let hit = new Audio();
let wall = new Audio();
let userScore = new Audio();
let comScore = new Audio();

hit.src = "sounds/hit.mp3";
wall.src = "sounds/wall.mp3";
comScore.src = "sounds/comScore.mp3";
userScore.src = "sounds/userScore.mp3";

// Ball object
const ball = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2,
    radius: 10,
    velocityX: 5,
    velocityY: 5,
    speed: 7,
    color: "WHITE",
};

// User Paddle
const user = {
    x: 0, // left side of canvas
    y: (canvas.height - 100) / 2, // -100 the height of paddle
    width: 10,
    height: 100,
    score: 0,
    color: "WHITE",
};

// COM Paddle
const com = {
    x: canvas.width - 10, // - width of paddle
    y: (canvas.height - 100) / 2, // -100 the height of paddle
    width: 10,
    height: 100,
    score: 0,
    color: "WHITE",
};

// NET
const net = {
    x: (canvas.width - 2) / 2,
    y: 0,
    height: 10,
    width: 2,
    color: "WHITE",
};


// draw a rectangle, will be used to draw paddles
function drawRect(x, y, w, h, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

// draw circle, will be used to draw the ball
function drawArc(x, y, r, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

// listening to the mouse
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getMousePos);

function getMousePos(evt) {
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    user.y = evt.clientY - rect.top - user.height / 2;
}

// when COM or USER scores, we reset the ball
function resetBall() {
    ball.x = canvas.width / 2;
    ball.y = canvas.height / 2;
    ball.velocityX = -ball.velocityX;
    ball.speed = 7;
}

// draw the net
function drawNet() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += 15) {
        drawRect(net.x, net.y + i, net.width, net.height, net.color);
    }
}

// draw text
function drawText(text, x, y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.font = "75px fantasy";
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

// collision detection
function collision(b, p) {
    p.top = p.y;
    p.bottom = p.y + p.height;
    p.left = p.x;
    p.right = p.x + p.width;
    b.top = b.y - b.radius;
    b.bottom = b.y + b.radius;
    b.left = b.x - b.radius;
    b.right = b.x + b.radius;

    return (
        p.left < b.right && p.top < b.bottom && p.right > b.left && p.bottom > b.top
    );
}

// update function, the function that does all calculations
function update() {
    // change the score of players, if the ball goes to the left "ball.x<0" computer win, else if "ball.x > canvas.width" the user win
    if (ball.x - ball.radius < 0) {
        com.score++;
        comScore.play();
        resetBall();
    } else if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width) {
        user.score++;
        userScore.play();
        resetBall();
    }

    // the ball has a velocity
    ball.x += ball.velocityX;
    ball.y += ball.velocityY;

    // computer plays for itself, and we must be able to beat it
    // simple AI
    com.y += (ball.y - (com.y + com.height / 2)) * 0.1;

    // when the ball collides with bottom and top walls we inverse the y velocity.
    if (ball.y - ball.radius < 0 || ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height) {
        ball.velocityY = -ball.velocityY;
        wall.play();
    }

    // we check if the paddle hit the user or the com paddle
    let player = ball.x + ball.radius < canvas.width / 2 ? user : com;

    // if the ball hits a paddle
    if (collision(ball, player)) {
        // play sound
        hit.play();
        // we check where the ball hits the paddle
        let collidePoint = ball.y - (player.y + player.height / 2);
        // normalize the value of collidePoint, we need to get numbers between -1 and 1.
        // -player.height/2 < collide Point < player.height/2
        collidePoint = collidePoint / (player.height / 2);

        // when the ball hits the top of a paddle we want the ball, to take a -45degees angle
        // when the ball hits the center of the paddle we want the ball to take a 0degrees angle
        // when the ball hits the bottom of the paddle we want the ball to take a 45degrees
        // Math.PI/4 = 45degrees
        let angleRad = (Math.PI / 4) * collidePoint;

        // change the X and Y velocity direction
        let direction = ball.x + ball.radius < canvas.width / 2 ? 1 : -1;
        ball.velocityX = direction * ball.speed * Math.cos(angleRad);
        ball.velocityY = ball.speed * Math.sin(angleRad);

        // speed up the ball everytime a paddle hits it.
        ball.speed += 0.1;
    }
}

// render function, the function that does al the drawing
function render() {
    // clear the canvas
    drawRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "#000");

    // draw the user score to the left
    drawText(user.score, canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 5);

    // draw the COM score to the right
    drawText(com.score, (3 * canvas.width) / 4, canvas.height / 5);

    // draw the net
    drawNet();

    // draw the user's paddle
    drawRect(user.x, user.y, user.width, user.height, user.color);

    // draw the COM's paddle
    drawRect(com.x, com.y, com.width, com.height, com.color);

    // draw the ball
    drawArc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, ball.color);
}

function RefreshWindow() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: on your update function, add pause flag so if the pause is true, dont do anything on update function. e.g. return

Answer (score 1):

First you should create a variable that records if the game is paused. And in your function that controls the canvas update every refresh, detect if the the game is currently paused by the variable you created. If yes, run the script you use to update canvas; If not, skip this turn.

In your html button, use its **onclick** property to flip the variable every click.

Example **HTML5**:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="flag=!flag">Pause</button>
```

Example **Javascript**:

```
//initialize
var flag=false;
```

```
//in update function
if(flag){
    //run the script
}
```